# Visual Studio for Mac - Can't read or write any code

Tags: vb.net, macos, visual-studio

I have a problem with Visual Studio for Mac. When I make a new project or I open an existent one, I can't read correctly the code or even write. The code is correctly, in others Text Editors looks fine, but in Visual don't.

[image]

Do somebody know about this error? thanks.

Comment: Scroll to the left.

Comment: No, I can't scroll to the left. Even applying bleeds I can't see the code. Looks like an error of Visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Visual Studio. 
(Click 'Visual Studio Community' in the top bar -> Check For Updates)

This must have been an early bug because I updated to 7.0.1 (Build 24) and it fixed the issue for me.